# AutoFixture Without() method does not work when there is only 1 constructor with all parameters?

Tags: c#, autofixture

I have the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
  public Foo(string id, 
     string name, 
     string? homeTown = null, 
     IEnumerable<string>? someCollection = null)
  {
     Id = id;
     Name = name;  
     HomeTown = homeTown;
     SomeCollection = someCollection;
  }

  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string? HomeTown {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<string>? SomeCollection {get; set;}
}
```

I want to create a mock with AutoFixture without filling HomeTown and SomeCollection.

But when I try to create it like this, the properties still get filled!

```
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();

    var dto = fixture.Build<Foo>()
        .Without(x => x.HomeTown)
        .Without(x => x.SomeCollection)
        .Create();
```

If I add another constructor without hometown and somecollection - it will work, but I don't want to add another constructor just to satisfy the tests.

Why is this behaviour? Is this some kind of a bug in AutoFixture?

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is the intended behavior of AutoFixture, and the way it is pushing developers toward a better design.

AutoFixture is a (opinionated) tool for TDD, built around the 80-20 rule, so it does make a few assumptions about how you will design your code, and it implements mostly features that are used in most common situations.

That said it is also a very open-ended tool that allows for a lot of flexibility. This means you can tell it to omit any optional parameters.

You could implement that by creating a builder that returns the default value set for the optional parameter and then omit all auto properties.

```cs
class OptionalParameterSpecification : IRequestSpecification
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(object request)
        => request is ParameterInfo parameterInfo
        && parameterInfo.IsOptional;
}

class DefaultValueParameterBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly IRequestSpecification specification;

    public DefaultValueParameterBuilder(IRequestSpecification specification)
    {
        this.specification = specification
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(specification));
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        if (!this.specification.IsSatisfiedBy(request)) return new NoSpecimen();
        if (request is not ParameterInfo parameterInfo) return new NoSpecimen();

        return parameterInfo.DefaultValue;
    }
}
```

Using the builder above, your test should look like this.

```cs
[Fact]
public void Bar()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(
        new DefaultValueParameterBuilder(
            new OptionalParameterSpecification()));
    fixture.Customize<Foo>(c => c.OmitAutoProperties());

    var foo = fixture.Create<Foo>();

    Assert.NotNull(foo.Id);
    Assert.NotNull(foo.Name);
    Assert.Null(foo.HomeTown);
    Assert.Null(foo.SomeCollection);
}
```